# Issue with loading png image from inifile

Tags: delphi, png, ini

I store PNG image into Ini file with the following code :

```
procedure TfrmParametres.SaveIni;
var
  IniFile: TIniFile;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  PNG: TPngImage;
begin
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create(IniFileName);
  try
  PNG := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    PNG.LoadFromFile(edtLogo.Text);//edtlogo contain image file path
    MS  := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      PNG.SaveToStream(MS);
      MS.Seek(0, 0);
      IniFile.WriteBinaryStream('REPORT_HEADER', 'LOGO', MS);
    finally
      MS.Free;
    end;
  finally
    PNG.Free;
  end;
finally
  FreeAndNil(IniFile);
end;
end;
```

and to show the picture in another form OnShow event I used the same approach :

1. Load DATA in TMemoryStream object
2. Load DATA from MemoryStream into TPngImage object
3. Show the picture in TImage component

   ```
   procedure TfrmLoadPicture.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
   var
     IniFile: TIniFile;
     MS: TMemoryStream;
     PNG: TPngImage;
   begin
     IniFile:= TIniFile.Create(frmParametres.IniFileName);
     try
       MS:= TMemoryStream.Create;
       try
         IniFile.ReadBinaryStream('REPORT_HEADER', 'LOGO', MS);
         PNG := TPngImage.Create;
         try
           MS.Seek(0, 0);
           PNG.LoadFromStream(MS);
           Image.Picture.Assign(PNG);
         finally
           PNG.Free;
         end;
       finally
         MS.Free;
       end;
     finally
       IniFile.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```

however I always get Exception error:
[image]

Comment: What's the size of your picture? TIniFile.ReadString reads at most 2048 characters.

Comment: I didn't used ReadString i used ReadBinaryStream instead ? ! did you means I need to set up the size of the memory stream ?

Comment: ReadBinaryStream uses ReadString.

Comment: [Note: When used with a Windows .ini file, ReadBinaryStream is limited to 1023 characters,](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/IniFiles_TCustomIniFile_ReadBinaryStream.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TIniFile` has a hard-coded cap on the size of any one value it can read, partly due to the fact the underlying Windows API (`GetPrivateProfileString` and friends) doesn't allow querying the size of a saved value. IMO `TIniFile` should really raise an exception on an attempt to write a larger value, but regardless, if you use `TMemIniFile` instead of `TIniFile` you should be fine (I've just tried it).

Answer (score 1):

Chris has answered the direct question that you asked. I have some other comments.

**No need to decode the PNG to transfer it to the INI file**

You can copy the file directly without decoding the PNG and then recoding.

```
Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
try
  IniFile.WriteBinaryStream('REPORT_HEADER', 'LOGO', Stream);
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

**Hexadecimal encoding is not efficient**

`WriteBinaryStream` is not a very efficient way to encode binary as text. In effect you are using base16 and it would be more conventional and efficient to use base64.

I suggest that you encode the binary file stream to a base64 string and write that string to the INI file.

**INI files are not suited to binary data**

INI files were never intended to be used to store large binary blobs. On first inspection it would seem odd that you are trying to shoe horn a PNG image into an INI file.